# Misnumbering of examples

Tags: numbering, mdframed

I am trying to use the mdframed package to create a boxed numbered Example environment. This is my first foray into environment definition, so I may be making a rookie mistake. Why doesn’t the numbering work correctly in this example? The examples appear to be numbered starting from 0 (which I don’t want) but when I reference them, the reference number is what I actually want (but not matching the printed example number).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%
% Example environment
%
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% set the counter for your environment
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter.\arabic{example}}

%% define the style
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
    frametitle=\mbox{},
    backgroundcolor=gray!8,
    linecolor=gray,
    outerlinewidth=1pt,
    roundcorner=3mm,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
}
%% setup the environment
\newmdenv[%
    style=example,
    settings={\global\refstepcounter{example}},
    frametitlefont={\bfseries Example~{\theexample}\quad},
]{example}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Blah}
qf;qiuef;iqugef;iqugef;
\begin{example}
blah blah blah
\end{example}
\begin{example}
blah blah blah
\end{example}

\chapter{Blech}
\begin{example}
Blech Blech Blech
\end{example}
\begin{example}\label{ex:blech}
Blech Blech Blech
\end{example}

Referencing Example \ref{ex:blech}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my machine; your example works exactly as it should (numbering starting from 1, not 0).

Comment: Your example works as it should. My system: MiKTeX 2.9 updated, Windows 7. Perhaps you have an older version of package example? Can you please check with '\listfiles'?  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: yes. The numbering of examples is done as we expected. Starts from one only

Comment: I'm the original poster. When I typeset this exact document, I get Example 1.0, Example 1.1, Example 2.0 and Example 2.1. What example numbering do y'all get?

Comment: I used `\listfiles` and see the results in the .log document. How can I share those results with you? It's too much text for this comment space.

Comment: Don't post the whole log. Just post the versions of the packages you are using and/or the distribution of TeX.

Comment: I'm not sure which portions are relevant. Here are some of possible interest (though these are just guesses):  ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)  
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features  
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01  
mdframed.sty    2013/03/09\ 1.8: mdframed  
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)  
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)  
md-frame-1.mdf    2013/03/09\ 1.8: md-frame-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that parts of your LaTeX is not up to date.

In your comment you said for example: `mdframed.sty 2013/03/09`. Mine is newer.

Here you have my result of \listfile.

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  xparse.sty    2014/07/20 v5241 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2014/07/20 v5241 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/07/20 v5241 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/06/30 v5166 L3 Unicode data
l3pdfmode.def    2014/07/18 v5232 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
needspace.sty    2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
md-frame-1.mdf    2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-1
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Please compare with your result and update the relevant packages.

The resulting numbering you can see here:

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks! I managed to make it work with the old version of the package by using `\newenvironment` instead of `\newmdenv`, following an example I found on this site.